# Erro ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT ao tentar aceder o WSDL

Tags: php, soap

Tenho um script PHP a ser executado na minha máquina local. O script está a consumir um web service SOAP.

Entretanto não consigo ter acesso ao WSDL.

Ao tentar abrir o link para o WSDL diretamente no browser, obtenho a seguinte resposta:

> This site can’t provide a secure connection
>
> domain.com didn’t accept your login certificate, or your login certificate may have expired. Try contacting the system admin.
>   ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT

Entretanto tenho 5 arquivos e não sei o que fazer com eles, mas penso que resolvem o problema acima, uma vez que se trata de um certificado. Os arquivos são:

> XXX.cer
>   XXX.csr
>   XXX.jks
>   XXX.p12
>   XXX.pem

O que preciso fazer com esses arquivos para ter acesso ao WSDL?